# How to do Y = aX + Y in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to do matrix operations using C++ STL containers.
There are two vectors of sizes say Y and X of sizes m,n(m>n). I want to multiply X with a scalar and add it from a given index in Y. In this process I don't want to transform X (don't want to use std::transform). In fact the X's are columns in a matrix DPtr. One version I tried  is given below.

```
    std::vector<double> D(&DPtr[index1],&DPtr[index1]+size_C);

    std::transform(D.begin(), D.end(), D.begin(),std::bind2nd(std::multiplies<double>(), val1*val2));

    std::transform (D.begin(), D.end(), YPtr.begin()+index2, YPtr.begin()+index2, std::plus<double>());
```

I am trying to copy the column in to a temporary vector and do operations on it.

Can some one help me in rewriting the code in a much simpler manner where I need not copy columns into another vector?

I am guessing I have to use std::for_each and lamda expression or a function call? But I am new to C++?

Just to give a lead, I want to write it as

```
std::for_each(YPtr.begin()+index2,YPtr.begin()+index2+(size_c-1),scalarAdd);
```

using a function scalarAdd or any lamda expression where I can access DPtr directly.
Also can I write

```
YPtr.begin()+index2+(size_c-1)
     .
```

as the second argument.Is it valid?
Also Imagine I made the matrix as a C++-vector where all columns of DPtr matrix are stored in one single C++ vector D.

[Visual Representation of my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei5z1.jpg)

Comment: I know this can be done with a single for loop in C. The point is to use STL::containers and hide details behind abstractions.

Comment: If you are also concerned with efficiency, I suggest you use a dedicated linear-algebra library. Have a look into Blaze, It is currently the fastest.

Comment: @MadhavGumma While hiding complexity behind abstractions is nice, in this case it is extremely important that the compiler is able to properly inline the `scalarAdd` function, e.g. by being able to optimise the supplied lambda and seeing the function definitions pointed to by all supplied function pointers. Otherwise, performance will go down considerably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest you use a dedicated linear-algebra library like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)? With that you could simply write `Y += X * a`, and the library+compiler will figure out the best implementation for you.

---

Since you are using C++11, you could use `std::transform` together with a lambda (`std::for_each` is not recommended since you need to transform your `Y`).

```
std::transform(DPtr.begin() + index1, DPtr.begin() + index1 + size_c, // X
               YPtr.begin() + index2,                                 // Y_in
               YPtr.begin() + index2,                                 // Y_out
               [](double x, double y_in) { return a*x + y_in; });
               // y_out = a*x + y_in, for every entry.
```